# Polymorphism Alternative Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

Here is how I'm handling comments without using actual Rails polymorphism:

```
class Comment < Active Record::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :class_name => "Commentable", :foreign_key => "commentable_id"
end

class Commentable < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "commentable"
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :class_name => "Commentable", :foreign_key => "commentable_id", :dependent => :destroy
  delegate    :comments, :to => :commentable

  before_create :make_commentable

  def make_commentable
    self.commentable = Commentable.new
  end
end
```

This works transparently, *except* the fact that when `make_commentable` is called, only sometimes does it create a Commentable record in the database. It seems to always work when using `rails s` but very sporadic when from `rails c`.

What's up?

EDIT

Should `self.commentable = Commentable.new` be `self.commentable = Commentable.create!` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `make_commentable`, use the Rails-provided `build_commentable` method.

Comment: So just do this: `before_create :build_commentable`, no other changes? I just ran it and I run into the same issue. A record does not get created. Using `create!` fixed the issue but I'm still confused by my original method using `new` had such sporadic results.

Comment: @Dex: Oh I see you want to create it. Then `:create_commentable` is what will create that object before create.

Comment: Okay that did work. Still wondering about the issue with `new` though.